# How to show a default page on a protected website running on IIS

Tags: iis, authentication, asp.net, iis-8.5

I can't figure out the correct syntax in my web.config to allow the general public to see the index.aspx as a default page and for any other page to go thru the login page.

If I use [www.mywebsite.com/index.aspx](http://www.mywebsite.com/index.aspx) the page is displayed fine and I don't have to go thru the login process. But if I try [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) I am being redirected to the login.aspx page. Is there a way to display index.aspx if no specific page is given?

```
 <!-- Allow the login page -->
 <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
 <!-- Allow the index.aspx page -->
  <location path="Index.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
<!-- deny the root folder -->
  <location path="">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

 ....

 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="GI" loginUrl="/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="/default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="180" />
    </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based upon [that comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/306896/how-to-stop-redirect-forms-authentication-from-root-url?rq=1) made a while ago. By adding a rewrite rule it did the trick, as 10 years have passed, since the post where I found the answer was written, perhaps now a smarter way exists.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite to Index.aspx">
  <match url="^$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="Index.aspx" />
</rule>
</rules>
```